# Accessing ipv6 resources from vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ipv6

I'm using vagrant with virtualbox provider and I can't figure out how to configure network to use ipv6 resources:

```
$ ping6 google.com
... 2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
$ vagrant ssh
vagrant$ ping6 google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
```

I've tried various network settings: `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "fde4:8dba:82e1::c4"`, `config.vm.network "public_network"`; neither of them seems work with ipv6.

Are there any known solutions?

Comment: Have you been assigned a Global IPv6 prefix? You cannot send traffic on the public Internet with a ULA (not Private) address, and you cannot simply make up a Global address.